# Confidence Intervals for Above Median and Below Median Differences of Same Data Set?

Tags: r

Make a 95% confidence interval for the difference in earnings between
above median height men and below median height men.

What programs/scripts would be helpful for a problem such as this in R?

Was able to use commands like:

```
# Use this command to calculate 95% confidence interval for difference in 
# height means between males and females
t.test(height ~ sex, data=CPS, conf.level=.95)
```

But cannot think of a way to find the confidence interval of below median and above median heights for the same dataset. Any tips? Sorry, new to R.

Comment: You need to clarify (in your own mind) the question you need to ask of the data first, and then you can begin to address how to implement it. Typing random lines of R code is not going to get you there. If you aren't clear about what statistical question to address, you'd probably be best to ask a (non-R) question on stats.stackexchange.com to start with. However, since this looks like homework you'd need to be careful to use the `self-study` tag there and follow the guidelines in its tag wiki (and also see the advice in the stats.SE on-topic help page).

Comment: For example, how is median height determined? From the sample? (and if so, how does that impact the inference, since that will destroy the independence assumption for starters; also if the relationship isn't step function which jumps at the median you'll get a biased estimate of the effect of height) ... Or is it determined externally?

Comment: Yes, is from a multi-thousand participant sample so didn't want to include data. Working on subsetting it now to become useful

Comment: > t.test(earnings, data=BelowMedianData & AboveMedianData, conf.level=.95) Error in t.test(earnings, data = BelowMedianData & AboveMedianData, conf.level = 0.95) : object 'earnings' not found I keep getting this error. Is there another way to ask what the 95% confidence interval for the differences of earnings in my datasets BelowMedianData and AboveMedianData in R?

Comment: "*is from a multi-thousand participant sample so didn't want to include data*" --- I take it then you didn't read the help before posting? The first page of help, [help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) mentions
minimal reproducible examples and points [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is the kind of thing you need here. Please don't post code in comments; fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

(Hints/outline of solution because this is homework.)

You don't make it clear what data you have. What are the variables and other information that's available?

My *guess* is (it's not stated clearly) you're intended to do this on the sample median height rather than some externally determined value for median height.

You'll need to construct a factor (at least implicitly) that indicates if height is greater than median height.

[Unfortunately, this invalidates the proposed test/confidence interval in the question -- see several posts on stats.stackexchange which discuss the issue -- but let's ignore that for now and treat it as a pure R-code issue.]

You'll then need to construct a confidence interval, perhaps using the example code in your question as a template.

Note that you're working with a subset of all people so you'll have to subset your data at some point, either before calling a function to do the CI, or within it. (That is, there are three variables in this problem, a response, a factor for comparing the response across and a variable for subsetting on.)

Comment: Yes, there's thousands of subjects for data so I didn't want to include it. Working on subsetting it to become useful. Sorry if this isn't the right place, but yes this is homework, professor expects us to teach ourselves how to use R and I've never used anything like this. Thought this might be a useful place to ask questions.

Comment: > t.test(earnings, data=BelowMedianData & AboveMedianData, conf.level=.95)
Error in t.test(earnings, data = BelowMedianData & AboveMedianData, conf.level = 0.95) : 
  object 'earnings' not found


I keep getting this error. Is there another way to ask what the 95% confidence interval for the differences of earnings in my datasets BelowMedianData and AboveMedianData in R?